# Are questions about SRS (spaced repetition memorization technology) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

[Spaced repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) is a technique for remembering facts efficiently.

Are questions about this technique and its implementation on-topic?

For instance:

- How to split a long text for efficient memorization using [Anki SRS](http://ankisrs.net/)?
- When starting to learn a new language, is it more efficient to memorize native->new or new->native?
- etc

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/40/89) suggests it's probably off-topic. *Framed correctly*, maybe it could find a home on [Cognitive Sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not active there and don't know their precise scope.

Comment: @Geobits I'm not sure of the precise scope of *either* site, but I think these questions would fit better on [Personal Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in no way authoritative, but... No.

The scope is still being defined, but one thing that seems clear, thus far, is that questions on Stack Exchange need answers that are somewhat definitive. Questions like those tend to lead to opinionated and relative answers; as in what works for you may not work for anyone else and that leads to situations where every answer is equally valid.